# Is it possible to add or update workflow from the client side by using REST Apis in Alfresco Activiti

Tags: javascript, java, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I am using activiti 5.22. I would like to show the bpmn diagram in frontend and also give the permissions to users to add or update Activiti workflow from frontend side(Reactjs/Angularjs) ?

Please help.

Comment: You will be more likely to receive good answers if you describe what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Activiti 5 ReST API is not rich enough to achieve what you are looking for.
In order to achieve this, you will need to enhance the API.
Keep n mind, even if you are able to allow users to modify a workflow, any process currently using the workflow will complete with the old version. Only new process instances will use the new workflow.

Comment: How I can enhance the API

Comment: Honestly, if this is what you want to achieve, then I would recommend you migrate to Flowable. Flowable extends on Activiti 6 and includes a modeling ReST API that will give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Greg Harley. I have looked into Flowable. 
https://flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch15-REST/ This is the link i have found for rest api. These are same as Alfresco Activiti api.
How I can edit the workflow from these API.
Do you have any exmaple? or can you please share the api link where I can edit the workflow. It will be great help

Comment: There is an additional undocumented API that is used by the web based designer.
You can find the endpoint details here: https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/tree/master/modules/flowable-ui

This provides API to crreate/update and delete a model in the system.
The code to generate the model is all client side I believe and can be found here: https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/tree/master/modules/flowable-ui/flowable-ui-modeler-frontend